# OnClick button replacing fragment many times with FragmentTransaction, ignoring Tag

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to make a quick simple app to learn lifecycle of both activities and fragments.

This is my onCreate:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity is created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("onCreate():","Activity is created");

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toMainFragment);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(MAIN);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(fragment == null) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, new MainFragment(), MAIN).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fragment already created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("onCreate():","Fragment Already created");
            }
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity restored data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("onCreate():","Activity restored data");
    }
}
```

However, every time I hit the button a new fragment gets created, even though I set the tag.

I thought the fragment would stay alive but is rather getting replaced. Why is this the case?

Comment: I think the downvotes are likely due to the vague title, but obviously I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is misplaced:

```
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(MAIN);
```

You have it outside of the `onClick()` method, which means that the value of `fragment` is determined once (when you create/assign the `OnClickListener`) and then reused every time the button is clicked.

Just move that line inside the `onClick()` method:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(MAIN);
        if(fragment == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, new MainFragment(), MAIN).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fragment already created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("onCreate():","Fragment Already created");
        }
    }
```